# Calculating Difference from two different lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, jython

I have two different sets of Lists and new list always have new value and i want to know how much the value has changed ?

```
previous=[ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[522, 'test', 'A4']]

current = [ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[622, 'test', 'A4'],[320, 'test', 'A5']]
```

for A4 the difference is 100 
How can able to calculate the difference ?

Desired output:

```
 A4 = 100
 A5 = 320
```

Comment: I would recommend using a dictionary if you are trying to keep track of a value (or values) for a specific key. Your example is also a bit confusing because there are multiple entries with "A4" but it sounds like this is also your key.

Comment: What if `current` contained `[622,'test','A4']` and `[623,'test','A4']`?

Comment: How would your desired output look like?

Comment: Do you want to subtract 'A4' from 'A4' only?

Comment: You aren't substracting anything from A5, though.

Comment: Check out `collections.namedtuple`. Having names assigned to values is really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code could solve your problem (I followed the idea of Chris Charley to use a  dictionary in order to map the keys `A3, A4, ...` to their integer values for each entry in the `previous` variable).

```
from operator import itemgetter

previous=[ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[522, 'test', 'A4']]
current = [ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[622, 'test', 'A4'],[320, 'test', 'A5']]

def differences():
    d = dict(map(itemgetter(2, 0), previous))
    for key, value in map(itemgetter(2, 0), current):
        difference = abs(d.get(key, 0) - value)
        if difference > 0:
            yield key, difference

output = dict(differences())
```

The output will be:

```sh
{'A4': 100, 'A5': 320}
```

`differences()` its a generator function that returns for each entry in the `current` list, a tuple with two items: The key `A*` and the amount of change between the `previous` and `current` lists (only if the difference is not 0)
e.g:
`('A4', 100)`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a crude workaround, and I agree that perhaps a dictionary would be a better option, but if you're adamant on sticking with lists:

```py
previous=[ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[522, 'test', 'A4']]

current = [ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[622, 'test', 'A4'],[320, 'test', 'A5']]


for i in range(len(current)):
    if i >= len(previous):
        print(str(current[i][2]) + " = " + str(current[i][0]))
    else:    
        if current[i][0]-previous[i][0]!=0:
            print(str(current[i][2])+" = "+ str(current[i][0]-previous[i][0]))
```

```
A4 = 100
A5 = 320
```

This'll all break down if the order changes at all (that is, if you are inserting rather than appending). There's also probably simplified ways, but this is the first thing I thought of given the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
previous=[ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[522, 'test', 'A4']]
df1= pd.DataFrame(previous,columns=['Score','test','name']) # creat a dataframe

current = [ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[622, 'test', 'A4'],[320, 'test', 'A5']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(current,columns=['Score','test','name']) # create another dataframe

df3 =df2.merge(df1,how='left',  on='name').fillna(0) # perform left join on key='name'

df3['diff']=df3['Score_x']-df3['Score_y'] # find the difference

df3[['name','diff']] # print the difference with current and previous
```

**Output**

```
name    diff
A3      0.0
A4      100.0
A5      320.0
```

Futher refinement:
If you do not want to display results with `diff=0`, then

```
df3[(df3['diff'] != 0)][['name','diff']]
```

**Output**

```
name    diff
A4     100.0
A5     320.0
```

If you need final result as dict

```
df3[(df3['diff'] != 0)][['name','diff']].to_dict('records')
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'A4', 'diff': 100.0}, {'name': 'A5', 'diff': 320.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary, `d`, as suggested by CMMCD:

```
>>> previous=[ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[522, 'test', 'A4']]
>>> current = [ [525, 'test', 'A3'],[622, 'test', 'A4'],[320, 'test', 'A5']]
>>> d = {a[2]: a[0] for a in previous}
>>> for data, _, key in current:
    if key not in d:
        print(key, '=', data)
    elif data != d[key]:
        print(key, '=', data-d[key])


A4 = 100
A5 = 320
>>>
```